# Is there a way to work-around site(s) breaking console.log

Tags: javascript, console.log

Excerpt of my Chrome DevTools Console:

```
Navigated to https://twitter.com/
console.log.toString();
"function (){}"
Navigated to http://linuxfr.org/
console.log.toString();
"function log() { [native code] }"
```

I managed to inject code in the main frame of twitter.com, using a Chrome Extension, but I had a hard time understanding why my code seemed to not run. It appears that my code is running fine, except `console.log` produces exactly nothing!

Question: is there a way to call the "now gone" `console.log` "native code"?

(remarks about that kind of JavaScript "WAT" behavior *retracted*, sort of)

Comment: Why does your extension need `console.log`?

Comment: @Bergi I don't need it, except as a tool when coding/debugging

Comment: If you set your content script to `run_at: "document_start"` - you could (theoretically) "grab" `console.log / error / dir / info` etc before twitter gets it's grubby hands on them :D

Comment: @JaromandaX  Works fine. Thanks!

Comment: BTW twitter.com currently has `console.trace` which can be used as a workaround. Not sure how long that will continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a Chrome Extension, you set your content script to `run_at: "document_start"` - you can(theoretically) "grab" `console.log` / `error` / `dir` / `info` etc before twitter gets it's grubby hands on them

actually, KNOWING that twitter only replaces log, warn, info, error, you can simply do:

```
var _console = ['log', 'warn', 'info', 'error'].reduce(function(result, key) { 
    result[key] = console[key].bind(console); 
    return result
}, {});
```

then you can use `_console.log` and friends

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "grab" thing. I used `window.ConsoleLogBackup = Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log;
 ConsoleLogBackup.apply(console,["Hello"] );`and I am now able to "log" in my script (and in the console) but I am not sure that kind of code is the right way to do it (and I would like to be abble to just type `ConsoleLogBackup("Hello")`

Comment: Take your time, it's LUNCH for me :-)

Comment: Second method works fine. First one gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` (event after fixing the upper case `C` in `Console.prototype`)

Comment: @manuell first code could be browser specific (firefox in my case) - second code should be generic enough ... will remove the first code from the answer

Comment: Try `Object.keys(console.__proto__.__proto__)` in Firefox. Ok in chrome.

Comment: Anyway, accepting as is, as I asked for `console.log`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it depends on how deep replacement was done.
For example if it was like this

```
 console.log = function () {};
```

The original native `log` function is still in prototype. You can access it using `__proto__` property or `Object.getPrototypeOf` method.

```
console.log = null
Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log
//log() { [native code] }
```

Also you can just delete replacement from original console object

```
delete console.log
//true
console.log
//log() { [native code] }
```

But all above code won't work if I replace log function like this

```
console.__proto__.__proto__.log = function () {}
```

And unfortunately I don't know workaround for this case.

Comment: FYI - `Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log.call(console, 'hi')` works as expected

Comment: @JaromandaX Indeed, on Twitter.com. Do you mean that it will "always" work?

Comment: I meant in the context of this question, i.e. twitter.com - which may be all the OP needs anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX I am the OP, and I just used Twitter as an example. I tried the `console.__proto__.__proto__.log = function () {}` code from Andrey, and then your workaround doesn't work anymore. That's sad, but thanks.

Comment: sorry, didn't read who wrote the comment :D ... yeah, the answer does state that if the site did that it could not be "worked around" - however, given you are using a Chrome Extension, I'm sure you can log to the console regardless of how a website tries to stop you - I don't know the inner workings of Chrome Extension that well - but if you delve into the documentation, I'm sure there's probably a simple way to log to the console independent of using a web page's window.console

Comment: actually ... `delete console.log` works just fine - but then twitter page could conceivably "detect" this change

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion above and @JaromandaX and [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) below is one simple polyfill.

```
function log() {
    if (location.hostname === 'twitter.com'){
        Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log.apply(console, arguments);
    } else {
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now gives “Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined”. Basically twitter.com has redefined `console` to not even have the native console as prototype. (`Object.getPrototypeOf(console)` is `{}`.)